# Java Graphics2D editing shapes after saving and opening an image

Tags: java, graphics2d

I have a quick question - I am making a simple shape editor in Java and it will have open and save feature. The point is that I make shae active by clicking on it, I can scale, drag it etc. By right-clicking I can change color. So I want these properties too when I open image I made previously. I was wondering if I would need vector graphics for that as it provides such behaviour but this is my first GUI in Java so I would like to hear comments from experts :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no really good way of getting shape data from only the image.
What you could do instead is storing your shape data for every shape in a file and read that file as input(that's how many other graphic do it).